# spark-submit fails with wrong IP reference

Tags: apache-spark

We are trying to run a sample python file through spark-submit , but it fails with the error as below.

we have also set SPARK_MASTER_IP and SPARK_LOCAL_IP to (10.1.1.127) in spark-env.sh file.

but some where still there is some refer to (ip-10-1-1-127)

```
 16/04/26 12:21:01 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
   java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-1-1-127: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at        java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
```

Comment: ./bin/spark-submit --master spark://10.1.1.127:7077 ...... (spark- prefix depend on which cluster manager do you use)

Comment: Thanks , now we are able to submit.